# Self Join on large tables slowness issue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables like...

- table1 (cid, duedate, currency, value)
- main_table1 (cid)

My query is like below, I am find out co-relation between each `cid` and `table1` contains 3 million records(`cid` and `duedate` column is compositely unique) and `main_table` contains 1500 records all unique.

```
SELECT 
    b.cid, c.cid, 
    (COUNT(*) * SUM(b.value * c.value) - 
                SUM(b.value) * SUM(c.value)) /   
    (SQRT(COUNT(*) * SUM(b.value * b.value) - 
                     SUM(b.value) * SUM(b.value)) * 
     SQRT(COUNT(*) * SUM(c.value * c.value) - 
                     SUM(c.value) * SUM(c.value))
    ) AS correl_ij
FROM 
    main_table1 a  
JOIN 
    table1 AS b ON a.cid = b.cid 
JOIN 
    table1 AS c ON b.cid < c.cid 
                AND b.duedate = c.duedate
                AND b.currency = c.currency 
GROUP BY 
    b.cid, c.cid
```

Please suggest how to optimize this query because it is running slow.

```
CREATE TABLE #table1(
    id int identity, 
    cid int NOT NULL,
    duedate date NOT NULL,
    currency char(3) NOT NULL,
    value float,
    PRIMARY KEY(id,currency,cid,duedate)
);

CREATE TABLE #main_table1(       
    cid int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    currency char(3)         
);
```

--#main table contains 155000 cid records there is no duplicate values

```
insert into  #main_table1 
values(19498,'ABC'),(19500,'ABC'),(19534,'ABC')

     INSERT INTO #table1(CID,DUEDATE,currency,value)
     VALUES(19498,'2016-12-08','USD',-0.0279702098021799) ,
    (19498,'2016-12-12','USD',0.0151285161000268),
    (19498,'2016-12-15','USD',-0.00965080868337728),
    (19498,'2016-12-19','USD',0.00808331709091531)
```

There are 3 million records in this table for diffrent dates and cid and most of the cid are present in #main_table1.

I am using   a.cid < b.cid  to remove duplicate relationship between a.cid and b.cid beause i am deriving corelation between each cid.

so 19498 -->>19500 corelation is calculated hence  then i do not want 19500--> 19498 because it would be same but duplicate.

Comment: do the arithmetic calculation in code level(whatever language you use in backend). handle the data fetch level logic in the query only.

Comment: i did not understand, please elaborate.

Comment: First, give us the full table definitions, including indexes. Next cover is the full execution plan of your query.  Why do you need `b.cid < c.cid`?  That's a triangular join and is very expensive, I'm not surprised it's slow. Roughly how many recurs did that job create? Finally, are you able to explain the calculations you're doing? There may be a better approach. Please use an English description AND give examples with dummy data.

Comment: :) what you do in the select statement is doing some sqrt and sum. if you handle it in backend level code like in c# or php or java or any other backend language, it would be a much faster query. because by separating them the query will be simplified and will operate to fetch data as fast as you can. Db commands are not at mathematical things but they are optimized for data level query.

Comment: Please give some table data.

Comment: @tazbirbhuiyan Please cite your references for such an extreme claim. Traditionally the joins are significantly more expensive than the scalar calculations. Additionally, if the GROUP BY reduces the data size by any appreciable amount the network costs in your suggestion will dwarf the scalar calculations.  Suggesting to do the aggregation remotely is, frankly, insane.  In this case the major source of cost is likely to be his triangular join.

Comment: Did every `cid` that exists in your data exist in `main_table1`, or is it just a subset in `main_table1`?

Comment: i have edited the question with all details please suggest.

Comment: KIndly suggest.

Comment: @TazbirBhuiyan that's 100% wrong. It will be *slower* - it will take the *same* time to pull all the data to the client *plus* the time to calculate the simple formulas there in a very inefficient manner. If you pull the raw data without aggregations, it will be A LOT slower. It's not the simple calculation that causes the delay. Besides, SQL Server uses SSE2 commands. Does your code do that?

Comment: @nextaxtion how slow is slow? Aggregating 3M rows without si going to take some time anyway. You can avoid the self join if you carefully use the `OVER()` clause in the aggregates to calculate running aggregates. This can still cause issues though, if the execution plan ends up performing a self join. You can use a *columnstore index* to make aggregate calculations a lot faster. You also get compression and in-memory processing for this

Comment: Try SELECT b.cid,  c.cid, COUNT(*) to see if the calculation is what is the problem

Comment: I cheked but calculation is not a problem here.

Comment: Then take the calculation out of the question if it is not a problem.

Comment: Out of my meetings and looking at this again. Does your update mean that you have no indexes?  Perhaps create some?  If a `cid` is not in your "main" table should it be excluded from all combinations? *(At present such a `cid` is never in `b`, yet Can appear in `c`.)*  For each `cid`, roughly how many rows do you have? For each `cid`, how many different currencies and duedates would there be?  Please could I ask again for the execution plan?  And I STRONGLY reiterate that you should give an example using dummy data.

Answer (score 1):

That PK is silly.  Why would you include Iden in a composite PK let alone in the first position?  Drop Iden unless you have to have it for some misguided reason.

```
PRIMARY KEY(cid, currency, duedate)
```

Or the natural key if different

Answer (score 1):

If you're commonly joining or sorting on the `cid` column, you probably want a clustered index on that column or a composite beginning with that column.

If `cid, duedate` is unique then you can consider removing the `id` altogether.

If you want to retain `id` for some reason, make it `PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED`, and specify a clustered index on `cid, duedate`.